# jQuery tabs losing its initialization

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

I have multiple instances of jQuery tabs on the same page. One of the instances is losing it's initialization. In other words, I initialize it just fine, but then later in the code, it is not initialized. I am wondering how to detect this condition. The ui-tabs classes are clearly present on the elements of the tab, but an attempt to do this fails:

$('#myTab')tabs('option')

Comment: is it just a typo that you are missing a `.` before `tabs` it should be like this `$('#myTab').tabs('option');`

Comment: Can you post an example that duplicates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem goes away when I check whether the widget exists in the _init code and if I find it, I destroy it and then recreate it.